# Copy constructor between derived classes

Tags: c++, oop, abstract-class, copy-constructor

How do you copy a derived class to another?

I'm terminologically deficient, so I'll try to illustrate with an example.

We are playing a card game with a computer player and human player. Card and Command are other classes.

```
class Player
{
    Card *Hand[4];
    // etc...
};

class Human: public Player
{
    Command getCommand();
    void PlayCard(Card card);
    void quit();
    // etc...
};

class Computer: public Player
{
    Command ai();
    void PlayCard(Card card);
    // etc...
};
```

And somewhere in the main function we have ...

```
// ...
Human p1; // Assume initialized and usable.
if(p1.getCommand() == QUIT)
{
    cout << "PLAYER 1 RAGEQUITS WHAT A NOOB LOL << endl;
    cout << "A COMPUTER WILL NOW TAKE OVER." << endl;
    p1.quit()
    p1 = new Computer(); // THE IDEA BEING THAT WE WANT TO PRESERVE p1's MEMBERS.
}
// ...
```

What I am trying to do is converting p1 to a "Computer" while preserving the state of its members.

Do we use a copy constructor to do this? If not, what methods do you use?

EDIT: Is this the way to use the assignment operator?

```
Computer& Human::operator=(const Human &h) // Assignment operator
{
    Hand = h.Hand;
    member2 = h.member2;
    member3 = h.member3;
    ...

    return *this;
}
```

Do we need to delete/free anything in the main?

Comment: Good news: you spelled "terminologically" right :)

Comment: It's `class`, not `Class`; and `public`, not `Public`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a design problem here. If you want to switch a player from a Human to a Computer while maintaining the common member variables then you should structure your classes in that way.

```
class Player
{ 
public:
    friend class Human;    // These friends are necessary if the controllers
    friend class Computer; // need access to Player's private data.

    Card hand[4];
    Controller* controller;
};

class Controller
{
public:
    virtual Command getCommand(Player const&) = 0;
};

class Human : public Controller
{
public:
    Command getCommand(Player const&) { /* get command from user input */ }
};

class Computer : public Controller
{
public:
    Command getCommand(Player const&) { /* get command from AI */ }
};
```

Then, when you need to switch from Human to Computer, just change the controller.

```
p1->controller = new Computer();
```

This way, the cards will be maintained, only the control mechanism will be changed.

Comment: That's another reasonable approach, although the `Controller` probably needs read access to the `Player`'s private data somehow.

Comment: In that case, either the Player could expose that data, or you could make the Controller a friend of the Player. That's what friends are for :)

Comment: It's not just an issue of access specifier, a pointer to the instance is also needed.  But this is easily solved also.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Yep, just realised that was what you meant. I've added the Player ref to the getCommand call :-)

Comment: Just add a player context and pass the controller an immutable reference to it.

Comment: Careful about leaking the old controller, of course.  Using `scoped_ptr<Controller>` would probably be good here.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a constructor. For this particular case I'd probably have a method called something like "CopyGameState".

Answer (score 2):

Copy constructor is used to copy an existing object a new instance of the same class.

What you need is an assignment operator (`operator=`), which allows assigning the value of a different type to your **existing** class object.

Comment: This is completely backwards, since it won't replace the vtable.

Comment: @Ben - you can't replace vtable of a constructed class.

Comment: Not without creating a new object... which is why the assignment operator isn't a good solution here.  He needs a new object, with a new vtable.

Comment: @Ben - he needs a redesign. I didn't clearly understand what the *real* problem is until after I read Peter's answer.

Comment: He wants `p1->PlayCard()` to start using `Computer::PlayCard` instead of `Human::PlayCard`, while keeping the member data intact.  Either @Peter's answer or mine will get him there.

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't be a copy constructor, but a converting constructor.  Something like:

```
Computer::Computer(const Player& had_to_go) : Player(had_to_go) {}
```

This will use `Player`'s copy constructor to preserve the members in the common base class.

Of course, you'd better make `Player::Player(const Player&)` work right, following the ["rule of three"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) and all.

In the end, you'd do something like:

```
p1.quit();
Computer* replacement = new Computer(p1);
delete p1;
p1 = replacement;
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what the "rule of three" is :P, also, is Player::Player(const Player&)      Player's copy constuctor?

Comment: @Ir Win: Yes, it's `Player`'s copy constructor, and the rule of three says that if you have a custom copy constructor, assignment operator, or destructor, you need all three.  In this case, it's because of the `Card*` stored in `Player`.  The compiler-provided copy will copy the pointer, which means you'll eventually delete it twice.  Not good.  There's a very good explanation in the C++-FAQ tag.  I'll add a link to it from my answer.